# Flux.map vs Flux.flatMap for a 1-to-1 operation

Tags: project-reactor

I keep seeing examples that use `flatMap` for a 1-to-1 operation, like:

```
Flux.just("a", "b", "c")
    .flatMap(s -> Mono.just(s.toUpperCase())
```

when I would have expected

```
Flux.just("a", "b", "c")
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
```

(Note: I know I didn't add a subscriber; assume I print them or something)

The use of `flatMap` here is to flatten the returned `Mono`, right? But why not just use the `map` operation as shown? Is it just because the `map` operation is synchronous? What use case am I missing?

Answer (score 12):

I don't think you are missing any. According to the documentation, flatMap is used when you require some asynch work to be done within it.

So the operation you would use here is simple map, since all you need is turn one object into another (lower case into upper case).

From what I noticed, if you want to turn one object into another map is enough. If you want extra asynch work done go with flatMap.